# Does a Java ByteArrayInputStream built off of bytes from a local String variable need to be closed?

Tags: java, inputstream, bytearrayinputstream

Let's say that I am constructing a Java `ByteArrayInputStream` off of a local String variable. For example, let's say that I have a large String named `csv` representing the contents of a CSV file and I need to put it into an input stream in order to have a component of my program read from that string, as opposed to from a file. For example,

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(csv.​getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

**Does this inputStream need to be closed once I am done processing with it?** I am aware that it is usually a good practice to close unused input streams, often via the try-resources construct. What I am specifically interested in right now is **what would be the consequences of choosing not to close this input stream before this variable goes out of scope when its method returns.** Would there be a memory leak because I left a stream open? Or would it not matter because the stream was open on a local variable instead of on a File resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You do not need to close a `ByteArrayInputStream`. Because it is in memory, there would be no consequences (it would be garbage collected). Now, if the `InputStream` was associated with an external resource (like a `File`) that could cause you to run out of file handles.

The [`ByteArrayInputStream` Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) says (in part),

> Closing a `ByteArrayOutputStream` has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

> I am aware that it is usually a good practice to close [...]

Then Just Do It (tm) :)

> what would be the consequences of choosing not to close this input stream before this variable goes out of scope when its method returns[?]

In the case of a `ByteArrayInputStream`, no consequence; for some other `InputStream` implementations, leaks, leaks and more leaks.

Long story short: always `.close()` safely, you never lose; either using a try-with-resources statement in Java 7+, or for earlier versions, ideally using [Guava's `Closer`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closer.html).